# Firestore Trigger in .NET

Tags: .net, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I am just getting started with Cloud Functions and Firestore. I have a function that does basic CRUD in Firestore and I am now looking to do some follow on processing when a document is updated.

I see documentation on defining a trigger in .NET but I can't find anywhere to tell Firestore that it exists.

Comment: I'm not clear what you mean by "I can't find anywhere to tell Firestore that it exists." Once you deploy a properly-configured trigger function to your project, that's all you have to do - it just works from that point on.  There is no more "telling" required.  If you've deployed a function and it's not working the way you expect, your question should show that code and explain how you reproduce the unexpected behavior.

Comment: I have a HTTP function that saves data to a Firestore collection. When I update a document in that collection, I want an onUpdate trigger to fire so that I can do some longer running post processing.

Where do I configure the connection between a collection being updated and the post processing function?

Comment: You don't configure anything outside of the function deployment itself.  If you're using gcloud to deploy your trigger, *all* of the configuration for that trigger is right there on the gcloud command line.

Comment: As @DougStevenson said, the connection is made when you deploy the function with gcloud.